# Apache Hadoop - node machine disparity?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I have an old desktop having an Intel dual core processor(32-bit) and I have Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop edition(again, 32-bit) running on it. I wish to set-up at least a 4-node Apache Hadoop cluster. For that, I'm planning to buy some used desktops which may come at a cheap price. However, I'm confused with the following queries :

1. Can Apache Hadoop work with disparate nodes in a cluster - one 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 while another is the 64-bit version ?
2. I think the O.S version has to be the same across the cluster nodes - am I correct?
3. As per the official site, 1.0.3 is the latest **stable** version - will it work with 32-bit machines or needs all the nodes to be 64-bit?

The answers to the above queries will help me to determine what kind of processor etc. must I purchase to build a cluster(*suggestions are welcome!!!*)

Comment: I'm still wondering why a '-1' for that question - I just had to get a few things clarified before I go ahead !!!

Answer (score 2):

> Can Apache Hadoop work with disparate nodes in a cluster - one 32-bit
> Ubuntu 12.04 while another is the 64-bit version ?
>
> As per the official site, 1.0.3 is the latest stable version - will it
> work with 32-bit machines or needs all the nodes to be 64-bit?

Everything runs on top of Java, so if you can install a 32bit Java, you can run Java. There are however some native parts, I believe they are crosscompiled working for x86 and x64.

Since the communication takes place via RPC (pure java code) this should work, although I haven't tried it out yet.

> I think the O.S version has to be the same across the cluster nodes - am I correct?

Not necessarily, but for the ease of your use in debugging problems and keep clusters homogenous in case of updates I wouldn't do this.